# Chaining python setup script executions

Tags: python, git

I have a python package that depends on two other python packages which I do not want to distribute as eggs or wheels.

I've set up my git modules file to pull these packages down, however, now I want to create my setup.py script for the main package such that it also runs the setup.py scripts for both submodules.

I can do this in a hacky way by adding the following to the main setup.py script:

```
# run the setup for the sub modules.
from subprocess import Popen
import os
import sys

dir1 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'src/module1')
dir2 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'src/module2')
# check to make sure the directories exist
if os.path.exists(dir1) and os.path.exists(dir2):
    install1 = Popen('cd '+dir1+'; python setup.py install;', shell=True)
    install2 = Popen('cd '+dir2+'; python setup.py install;', shell=True)
else:
    print "sub-modules not found, did you clone with the recursive tag?"
sys.exit()
```

However, I'd like to know if there is an accepted way of doing this using setuptools or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distribute your application with all dependent modules you may use `pip` with `requirements.txt` in the root folder of your main package.

Namely, you install the additional packages with

`pip install git+git://github.com/myuser/foo.git@v123
...`

Then dump the list of installed packages

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

And finally add into Readme the following installation step

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Pip automatically runs `setup.py` in submodules so there's no need to run them explicitly.

Comment: Nice answer, I didn't know that pip could do that!